# fetch groups using Regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String **"UPDATE TEMP SET COL1 = -1 ,  COL2 = 'val' Where COL3 > 45"**

```
Now I want to fetch the following
```

- get the string value just after UPDATE which is **TEMP**
- get all groups    after Set which is **COL1=-1** and **COL2 ='val'**
- get whole string after    COL2='val' which is **Where COL3 > 45**

I want to do that in java using pattern matching

This is what I had tried but i need some better approach

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^UPDATE (\\w+) (SET) (.*) (WHERE.*)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s.toUpperCase());
        if (m.find()) {
            String group1 = m.group(1);
            String group3 = m.group(3);
            String group4 = m.group(4);
            System.out.println("Group1: "+group1);
            System.out.println("Group3: "+group3);
            System.out.println("Group3: "+group4);
        } else {
            System.out.println(" No match found");
        }
```

Comment: Go ahead. What's stopping you?

Comment: Come on, at least write one line of code.

Comment: What is wrong with your code ?

Comment: i am new to regex pattern and this code wont work when i gave multiple spaces after table name though i came to know the solution now , thanks all

Comment: yes it worked , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that:

```
update\s+(\w+)\s+|(\S+\s*=\s*\S+)(?=.*where)|(where.*)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CexGxD/4/)

Explanation:

**case 1:**

`update\s+(\w+)\s+`

look for the string **update** followed by white line `\s+` ... followed by `\w+` i.e. `a-zA-Z0-9` multiple time which in your example is **TEMP** followed by one or more whitespace i.e. `\s+`

**case 2:**

```
\S+\s*=\s*\S+(?=.*where)
```

`\S+` nonwhitespace chracters in your case **COL1**, followed by one or more whitespace character, followed by =, followed by one or more whitespace character , followed by non whitespace character in your example **-1** or **val**

`(?=.*where)`

it ensures that this key value pairs are leading a where in the end

**case 3:**

```
(where.*)
```

it captures everything starting from where to till the end

> Sample Java Source

( [run here](https://ideone.com/5GoC5p) ):

```
final String regex = "update\\s+(\\w+)\\s+|(\\S+\\s*=\\s*\\S+)(?=.*where)|(where.*)";
final String string = "UPDATE TEMP SET COL1 = -1 , COL2 = 'val' Where COL3 > 45\n";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        if(matcher.group(i)!=null)
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Stop answering no-effort questions! The value of StackOverflow is in having good questions and answers searchable through Google. It's not a help-me-now forum site. Answering terrible questions diminishes the value of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Rizwan-  could you please let me know what do i need to change if there are some spaces in value like the value of COl1 has space in concat(-1, 3) please check this string "UPDATE TEMP SET COL1 = concat(-1, 3) , COL2 = 'val' Where COL3 > 45"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?sim)update\s(.*?)\sset\s(.*?)\s(where=?.*?)$
```

`Group 1` - TEMP

`Group 2` - COL1=-1 and COL2 ='val'

`Group 3` -    Where COL3 > 45